# Is there a way to numerically resize and position stardock fences

Tags: fences, stardock

So, I hate trying to drag and resize fences, I can almost never get them correctly sized or spaced and while it helps my desktop organization, the offsets just bug me. Is there a way to manually size them numerically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regedit to manually edit the position and size of fences. I don't know that you can easily create new fences this way (It almost looks like stardock is using the registry like a relational database), but the sizing part is easy. Navigate to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Stardock\Fences\Groups. I just exported the registry key and modify the text file, then run it to load it back into the registry. Much easier than the drag to resize interface.

The syntax of the keys as far as I can tell is as follows

[fence id]|[left position]|[top position]|[width]|[height]|[???]|[fence name]|[followed by several lines concerning monitor data, not sure what these are for but they don't need to be editted for positioning]